# How to convert dataframe to Rules (arules package)?

Tags: r, dataframe, rules, arules

I converted some rules to a dataframe with the DATAFRAME() fx from arules package. I deleted some rules and I want to convert back to class rules. I looked for documentation but I cannot find anything to do this.

I already tried to coerce:

> as(df_br_two, "rules")
>   Error in as(df_br_two, "rules") : 
>     no method or default for coercing “data.frame” to “rules”

I need to convert back to rules so I can plot the rules with arulesViz. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can change the data.frame back to a rules structure, at least not simply. However, if what you want to do is eliminate some of the rules, you can leave them as rules and edit easily.   For example,

```
library(arules)
data("Adult")
rules <- apriori(Adult, 
    parameter = list(supp = 0.7, conf = 0.9, target = "rules"))
rules
```

> set of 17 rules

Now let's eliminate the first and third rules

```
rules = rules[-c(1,3)]
rules
```

> set of 15 rules

Comment: Thanks! the thing is it's much more complex like that to eliminate some rules, but you gave me the idea to make a copy of the rules, change that copy to DF and get the indexes of the rules I need to delete, and then delete them in the original rules. Although, I would like to convert them back to rules, this is another approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The rCBA package has a function called frametoRules.

This function will take a dataframe that was just converted from a rules back to rules. The only downside is that the function doesn't work consistently.

https://github.com/jaroslav-kuchar/rCBA/issues/6

This is the link to the issue.

Maybe you get lucky and it works for you? Who knows?

```
# Make sure that your dataframe is in this format :

data.frame(
           "rules" = {lhs} => {rhs},
           "support" = 0.5,
           "confidence" = 0.5,
           "lift" = 1.0)
)

newrules <- frametoRules(dataframe)
```

Good luck!

More Documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rCBA/versions/0.4.3/topics/frameToRules